# Symfony 3.4 - is there a way to create an auto-incrementing id for a ChoiceType?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a `ChoiceType` that is rendered as a series of radio buttons:

```
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    $choices["{$card->brand} **** **** **** {$card->last4}"] = $card->id;
}

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('card', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $choices,'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false])
    ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm()
```

I'd like to have an incrementing id for each choice, something like 'card1', 'card2', etc., but am unsure how to actually do it.  The choices themselves are dynamically created - I don't know ahead of time how many choices (if any) will be present.

Ideally, there'd be some kind of internal counter I could access in 'choice_attr' and/or 'choice_label', but I don't see anything like that in the docs.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Create a counter variable outside and count it for each of your choices. For adding the id use the [choice_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) option:

```
$i = 0;

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('card', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'choice_attr' => function() use ($i) {
            $i++;
            return ['id' => 'choice-'.$i];
        },
    ])
```